How to fit spin spiral calculations to J1-J2-J3 Heisenberg model?
I recently read some papers (e.g., this) that performed spin spiral calculations to get exchange interactions J1-J3. They did the calculations for q vectors along a path connecting high symmetry points, and fit the energies to the Heisenberg model:
$$\tag{1}
H = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{ij} J_{ij} S_i.S_j
$$
I used VASP to get the energies of the system as I changed the q ordering vector from Gamma (0,0,0) --> M (0.5,0,0) --> K (1/3,1/3,0) --> Gamma, with discretized points in-between to get a high-resolution line.
I am having trouble fitting these energies to the Heisenberg model to get J1-J2-J3. I have a 2D triangular lattice, with displacement vectors in real space given by:
R1 = np.array([[1, 0], [0.5, np.sqrt(3)/2], [-0.5, np.sqrt(3)/2],
               [-1, 0], [-0.5, -np.sqrt(3)/2], [0.5, -np.sqrt(3)/2]]) * a
R2 = np.array([[1.5, np.sqrt(3)/2], [0, np.sqrt(3)], [-1.5, np.sqrt(3)/2],
               [-1.5, -np.sqrt(3)/2], [0, -np.sqrt(3)], [1.5, -np.sqrt(3)/2]]) * a
R3 = R1 * 2

I then try to fit to the following function, following many references (I am guessing it is because $J_i \rightarrow J_i e^{q.R}$, and we take only the real cosine part?):
$$
E_0 + J_1 cos(q.R) + J_2 cos(q.R) + J_3 cos(q.R),
$$
where $E_0$ is a reference energy constant. I use the following code:
def extended_energy(q, J1, J2, J3, E0):
    qx, qy = q[:, 0], q[:, 1]
    # Heisenberg terms
    cos_q_d1 = sum(np.cos(qx * R[0] + qy * R[1]) for R in R1)
    cos_q_d2 = sum(np.cos(qx * R[0] + qy * R[1]) for R in R2)
    cos_q_d3 = sum(np.cos(qx * R[0] + qy * R[1]) for R in R3)
    # Total energy
    return E0 + (J1 * cos_q_d1 + J2 * cos_q_d2 + J3 * cos_q_d3) 

Above, qx and qy are from the q vectors I used.
When I used a least squares fitting, the fit isn't that good. Fitting code:
def residuals(params, q, E_data):
    J1, J2, J3, E0 = params
    E_model = extended_energy(q, J1, J2, J3, E0)
    return E_data - E_model

# Initial guess for parameters
initial_guess = [0.005, 0.001, 0.001, np.min(E)]

# Perform least squares fitting
result = least_squares(residuals, initial_guess, args=(q_physical, E))

Above, E are my energies as a function of q (energy from VASP for each q I chose).
Could someone please help me understand what I must do to correctly extract $J_i$ (treatment of qxqy, output of magnetization, other factors/constants, etc)?

Just a comment: The cosines in your dispersion are probably not from taking the real part, but because sites of the triangular lattice are inversion centers such that there are neighbors with displacement $\pm \mathbf{R}$ that will both show up in the lattice summation.
